# How to fix 'TypeError: Error #1009' error in ActionScript3.0 Adobe Animate

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm setting up a button on the first frame which when clicked will transfer the user to the 2nd frame using this code:

```
    stop();

    Btn_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2);

     function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame_2(event:MouseEvent):void
     {
 gotoAndPlay(2);
     }
```

and on the second frame, I set up a dynamic text that will perform a countdown using this code:

```
    var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,60); // every second for 60 seconds
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
    myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onComplete);
    myTimer.start();

    function onTimer(e: TimerEvent):void {
countdown_text.text = String(myTimer.repeatCount - myTimer.currentCount);
     }


     function onComplete(e: TimerEvent):void{
     gotoAndStop(3);
     }
```

the thing is keep getting TypeError: Error #1009 message after debugging it. I know the fault is in line 7 of the 2nd code but I have no idea what is wrong with it. Pls help!

Comment: Have you defined countdown_text? Error 1009 is referred about a null object, so if countdown_text is null you can't access to its properties (i.e. text)

Answer (score 0):

I should see your source fla, but it is most likely related to countdown_text not being accessible in that frame. Error description is "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference", that means it cannot find the reference which is "countdown_text".
It is very very bad practice to write AS directly in frames. Convert code into a class and assign it as a document class.
You can find Adobe documentation for document class here: https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/actionscript-publish-settings.html

Comment: It is not necessarily bad practice. For some simple and straightforward application, there is absolutely no need to go the extreme of writing everything in classes. Best practices only go as far as it serves you.

Comment: True, although this doesn't seem the case at all to me. A real pitfall, re-instanciating timers whever playhead goes on frame 2.  Plus, it seems the user will benefit from understanding the use a document class, that would make what he is trying to do much simpler and bug free. He probably wounldn't even have to post a question here with some cleaner code.

Comment: I think it really boils down to how complex the project is. For simple page by page application OP is doing, the amount of time saved and the reduced complexity of using timeline far outweighs the small memory setbacks like re-instantiating a timer. I too am in favor of using classes, but sometimes a ugly solution is smaller and more understandable. I get where you are coming from though.